# After using Navigation.PushAsync, the navigation menu disappears

Tags: xamarin, navigation

I have an authorization method, after successfully logging in, I want the user to move to the main page of the application, but when using Navigation.PushAsync, the navigation menu stops being displayed, and an arrow appears in its place, which returns to the authorization form. How do I go to the main page with the menu saved?

```
if (loginResponse != null && loginResponse.user != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginResponse.access_token))
{
    UserData user = new UserData
    {
        name = loginResponse.user.name,
        email = loginResponse.user.email,
        created_at = loginResponse.user.created_at,
    };
    Debug.WriteLine($"Получен пользователь: {user.name}, Email: {user.email}, Создан: {user.created_at}");

    await SecureStorage.SetAsync("AccessToken", loginResponse.access_token);

    UserDataHolder.SetUserData(user);

    await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
}
```

Comment: Are you using [shell as the visual hierarchy of the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/create?view=net-maui-7.0)? In addition, can you provide more code information to facilitate my testing?